# Error:non static method 'edit' cannot be referenced in static context

Tags: android

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testpref";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLyout;

    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}


public void setUp(DrawerLayout drawerLayout,Toolbar toolbar) {
    mDrawerLyout=drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLyout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}
 public void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue)
 {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=SharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

So i am having error on the line,
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=SharedPreferences.***edit();***

> Error:non static method 'edit' cannot be referenced in static context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
```

instead of

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=SharedPreferences.edit();
```

You can not directly `SharedPreferences.edit();`.

You have to create object of `SharedPreferences` and You have created which is `sharedPreferences` so use it to call `edit()` method.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Error:non static method 'edit' cannot be referenced in static context

means `edit` is non-static method, so need to create object of `SharedPreferences` class for accessing method.

In current code `sharedPreferences` is object which can be used for accessing non-static methods from `SharedPreferences` class :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = (SharedPreferences.Editor) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

You can use it like this.